# Changing title and options in javascript confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, dialog, confirm

I want to add my project title to a javascript confirm dialog, and want to change "Ok" and "Cancel" to "Yes" and "No". How can I do this?

Answer (score 9):

We can't override the functionality of the JS . But you can show your project name on top by using  the trick "nextline(/n)"  as i did in  my project :)

This is just an trail solution for your satisfaction . :)

```
confirm("ProjectName \n\n\n\n\ some question goes here ");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're talking about `confirm` function in javascript, well, you can't change its properties. I suggest look into using a custom confirm dialog box e.g. jQuery UI's [modal confirmation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation). You have many options out there and by using custom ones you have a lot of things you can do, you can even change colors of the box if you want. Just an idea :)